# Where can i find good material for Travis Bintray integration?

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

I've started to build a small opensource project .

Below is my setup :
1) Project is in github . Currently uses maven .
2) Has webhook for automatic Travis builds .
3) Trying to configure to have artifactory in Bintray Jcenter.

Last couple of days I've tried hard for integrating travis and Bintray with no luck (Esp with Bintray Encryption). Only material i found were from 
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/bintray/ .But that one is clearly not helping me with my issue .

Comment: That's the official documentation. If something doesn't work for you, maybe it's worth posting a particular question.

Comment: I did post another question about that .. But was trying find if there other source of documentation . thanks

Comment: Link, please, I'll take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356238/issue-using-encrypted-bintray-key-in-travis-yml