# Issue using Encrypted bintray key in travis.yml

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

**So When i use the below in .travis.yml it works ..**

```
*********************
    deploy:
      user: mybintrayuserid
      provider: bintray
      file: .bintray_descriptor.yml
      key: myapikey

***********************
```

**but if i change this to below i get error:**

```
**************************
deploy:
  user: mybintrayuserid
  provider: bintray
  file: .bintray_descriptor.yml
  key:
    secure: encryptedHashHash
****************************
```

**Error that i get :**

[Bintray Upload] Bintray response: 401 Unauthorized. This resource requires authentication .

**How i generated the key :**

```
travis encrypt myapikey --add deploy.key
```

Note: I've added screenshot too for more details ..

**Screenshot :**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhkgJ.png

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use the correct user also.

In my case, I was trying to deploy to a repo owned by an organization, and I wrongly configured the `user` as the organization name.

Instead of using the organization as the `user` in your `.travis.yml` you must use your the username associated with the API key.

I have both the user and the key encrypted - and working.

Comment: as mentioned aboeve i did use my user id and not organization name

Comment: @Dhyan, i think this answer is correct. In my case a user name and a repository name have matter. But i should add that i am talking not about a user name you add to key 'user:'. I am talking about group 'user/repo' you used for generation a secured key.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the same thing happens to me. I assume it's a failure with the Bintray plug-in as the notion of a secure token isn't native to the Bintray API but part of the Travis integration provided by Travis.